# Endpoint for Cloud Function returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-iam

I am following Google's [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions) for setting up an Endpoint for my cloud function.

When I try to access the endpoint from my browser using URL `service_name.a.run.app/function1` I get

```
Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /function1GET from this server
```

As part of the mentioned tutorial and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006993/hide-cloud-functions-execution-behind-cloud-endpoints) from a Google product manager , I'm securing my function by granting ESP permission to invoke my function.

```
gcloud beta functions add-iam-policy-binding function1 --member "serviceAccount:id-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" --role "roles/cloudfunctions.invoker" --project "project_id"
```

My `openapi-functions.yaml`

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Cloud Endpoints + GCF
  description: Sample API on Cloud Endpoints with a Google Cloud Functions backend
  version: 1.0.0
host: HOST
x-google-endpoints:
- name: "HOST"
  allowCors: "true
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /function1:
    get:
      operationId: function1
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/function1GET
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
```

Note that I added

```
- name: "HOST"
  allowCors: "true'
```

to my `.yaml` file because I need to access the endpoint from a static site hosted on Firebase.

Comment: Where is hosted your ESP?

Comment: My ESP is in Cloud Run using a URL similar to gateway-12345-uc.a.run.app

Comment: can you run this command and add the result here? `gcloud run services describe <your service>`

Comment: Turn on the browser debugger. Post the output of a request including the headers. Note that the request requires an HTTP `Authorization: TOKEN` header. Without that header, you will receive a permission error.

Comment: allowCors: true inside x-google-endpoints doesn't work for Cloud Run ESP.  You need to use ESP_ARGS flag to specify CORS flags to ESP.  Please check the bottom of the doc: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have followed the tutorial you have mentioned, and indeed I came across the exact same error.

Nothing regarding permissions and roles seemed wrong.

After digging a bit what solved the issue was removing the “`GET`” at the end of the address.

So the `openapi-functions.yaml` would be like this:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Cloud Endpoints + GCF
  description: Sample API on Cloud Endpoints with a Google Cloud Functions backend
  version: 1.0.0
host: [HOST]
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /function-1:
    get:
      summary: Greet a user
      operationId: function-1
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://[REGION]-[PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/function-1
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
```

Then make sure you are following all the steps mentioned in the tutorial correctly (except the above part).

In case you get a Permissions Denied error when running any of the steps, try running it again as `sudo`.

I have also tried adding the same as you:

```
host: [HOST]
x-google-endpoints:
- name: [HOST]
  allowCors: "true"
```

And all is working well.

Pay extra attention to the `CONFIG_ID` that changes with each new deployment
Example:

```
2019-12-03r0
```

then it goes like:

```
2019-12-03r1
```

In case the deployment step fails (it shows some successful messages but it might fail in the end), then make sure you delete the existing endpoint service to avoid issues:

```
gcloud endpoints services delete [SERVICE_ID]
```

Also you can use the following to give `cloudfunctions.invoker` role to all users (Just for testing)

```
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding function-1 \
 --member="allUsers" \
 --role="roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
```

Comment: Btw, I work for Google Cloud Support so I will make sure to report this to the Documentation team to be reviewed and avoid possible confusion in the future.

Comment: Thanks Waelmas, this solved my CORS problem. I am now running into an issue with passing a `path parameter` in my `openapi.yaml` --- was wondering if you could take a look  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165012/passing-a-path-parameter-to-googles-endpoint-for-cloud-function