# Allowing internal traffic only for cloud function behind cloud endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am currently setting up a series of cloud functions behind cloud endpoints (ESPv2).

I already secured cloud functions by allowing only authenticated traffic from the cloud run service (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006993/hide-cloud-functions-execution-behind-cloud-endpoints)).

I was wondering if it were possible to also select "internal traffic only" as the ingress setting. I tried but I only get 403s when I enable it.

This option should "*only allow traffic from the same project or VPC*". The cloud run service is in the default VPC and both the function and service are in the same project.

---

**Edit:**

Function works and is available here:
https://europe-west1-iota-beta-296214.cloudfunctions.net/api-keys

Accessing it through ESPv2 (Cloud Run) returns a 503 when using a VPC Connector (it works if no connector)
https://functions.getiota.fr/auth/jwks

Cloud Run image was built following [google's tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions) using a specific service account and VPC Connector ([see CLI doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy))

Here is an extract of my endpoint service conf:

```
...
host: functions.getiota.fr
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /auth/jwks:
    get:
      summary: Get the JSON web key set for authentication
      operationId: jwks
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://europe-west1-iota-beta-296214.cloudfunctions.net/api-keys
        protocol: h2
...
```

---

**Edit 2 with workaround:**

After following the answer below, everything works fine if the ESPv2 is deployed on cloud run with `--set-env-vars=ESPv2_ARGS=--backend_dns_lookup_family=v4only`. This option is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/specify-esp-v2-startup-options#platform).

I followed with this issue on ESPv2's github: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2/issues/423

Comment: where did you deployed your ESPv2?

Comment: In the default VPC I am guessing? I did not specify any location.

Comment: Ok, you deployed ESPv2 on Cloud Run right? And you are able to reach your private function by using the identity of your Cloud Run service, correct? Now, same configuration but use ingress=internal parameter, isn't it?

Comment: This is exactly whaat I tried. But I get 403 errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to add a [serverless VPC Connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) to your Cloud Run instance that host ESPv2, and to [route **all** the egress traffic to this connector](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc).

```
gcloud beta run services update <SERVICE ESPv2> \
  --vpc-connector projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/<REGION>/connectors/<CONNECTOR_NAME> \  
  --vpc-egress all
```

*Note: the connector must be in the same region as the Cloud Run service. Check [the supported region](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#supported_regions)*

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, I now get a different error though:
_upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure_
When I google that I mostly get Istio error. I am guessing it has something to do with Envoy ?

Also noting:
- this happens regardless of the function ingress setting
- digging into the cloud run logs, I get a _PERMISSION_DENIED:Calling Google Service Control API failed with: 403_. I'll solve that now, see if it helps.

Comment: Strange. I tested yesterday and it worked perfectly! Where do you see this error? Can you share the logs and your configuration?

Comment: Any good way of sharing the configuration? (sorry I am new to this).
Basically I have:

- a service account with _Cloud Functions Invoker_ and _Service Controller_ roles
- a VPC connector to the default VPC
- a cloud run _instance_ running a built ESPv2 image with that service account
- a cloud function

All of these are in `europe-west1`.
In the logs, there is nothing interesting except:

`Failed to call report, error: PERMISSION_DENIED:Calling Google Service Control API failed with: 403 and body: The caller does not have permission`

Comment: Are the Cloud Run ESP and the CLoud Function in the same project?

Comment: Yes, everything is in the same project and region.

Comment: And with the vpc-egress to all I guess. Do you have a VPC Service control activate on the project?

Comment: By _VPC Egress to all_ do you mean that when I add the connector I select all traffic to VPC?
No VPC service control. Do you have any idea why I would get a Service Control 
 permission denied when I route all traffic through the VPC?

Comment: Yes, I means route all the traffic through the VPC connector. Did that you do?

Comment: Yes. I am going to start a new project from scratch. Maybe I messed up something.

Comment: Arf i still get the 503 in a completely new project / VPC. Do I need any specific firewall rule maybe?

Comment: It's maybe too quick. Cloud Endpoint need some minutes to discover and to load for the first time the API (and to take into account the change, especially for the security definitions). Do you still have a 503 error?

Comment: I just set it up again using the default VPC in a new project: https://functions.getiota.fr/auth/jwks. Still the 503. What IP range did you select for the connector when you set it up?

Comment: The IP range doesn't  matter if the range don't overlap an existing one. So, your function is working, but the ESPv2 on Cloud Run redirection doesn't?

Comment: Yes. Only if I route the traffic through the VPN Connector and regardless if the function is internal only or not

Comment: 503 it's like if the ESPv2 proxy wasn't up. You can test with a not private function, like an hello world to confirm that the ESPv2 is working.

Comment: I added a bunch of info with the URLs and part of the conf. Maybe I missed something stupid. When you say ESPv2 you mean the cloud run instance, right? It works if I do the exact same image with no connector.
There is also no useful info in the logs. it just says that it returned a 503...

Comment: If the connector that cause the issue?

Comment: It's adding the connector that does yes.

Comment: Do you have firewall rules that block the outgoing traffic? Because, if it's work without the VPC connector, but  you can't serve traffic with it, there is something in your VPC that block the traffic. And, because you are in your VPC, the firewall rules and the routes are enforced

Comment: I tried adding firewall rules to allow all ingress and egress on all ports (I was that desperate) but it didn't change anything.
However I got it working by adding `--set-env-vars=ESPv2_ARGS=--backend_dns_lookup_family=v4only` to only use IP v4... Got that idea from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2/issues/170. Going to accept your answer, edit my issue and create an issue on github unless you have an idea why?